# Can't play HTML5 video using Flask

Tags: python, flask, html5-video

I'm using Flask to serve .m3u8 and .ts files to simulate a vod stream.

The video player does not stream the file and shows an error (see the screenshot below).  I can't find a log of what error it is.

[image: screenshot of error]

Is there a log message somewhere that I'm missing?  What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The development server runs in single threaded mode by default, meaning it can only handle one request at a time.  You are requesting streams of two files at once, the .m3u8 and the .ts.  You can pass [`threaded=True` or `processes=value greater than 1` to `app.run`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.9/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) to allow handling of multiple requests at once, but that comes with it's own problems.  The development server in general seems to have problems streaming html5 video and audio.  The real solution is to use an actual server such as Nginx or Apache to serve the media files.